# How to get higher specs just for a day for EC2 due to anticipated high usage?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

I'm running on the Free Tier AWS EC2 currently (Ubuntu with Wordpress Website on NGINX, MySQL etc). I am expecting very heavy load usage just for a couple of hours for one day in the coming week, and I would like to know if there is a way that I can pay for higher specs instance just for that short period. I think it will be primarily cpu, memory & network intensive with the web server coping with hits on the website when a sale we're conducting opens.

Not sure if that is possible? Would greatly appreciate anyone who can advise me on how to cope with the anticipated heavy traffic to my webserver from a lot of users just for that day. We're willing to pay for it, just don't know how to do it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would have to do that manually.  An EC2 can be changed to a different instance type but it requires stopping the machine and restarting it with the new instance type.  You will likely be billed for the higher spec machine.  After you're done you'll have to "undo" the upgrade and go back to a lower spec.  In general a production website would scale horizontally - i.e. a fleet of cheap machines clustered and scaling up and down as needed.

Comment: You can instead provision a second machine while keeping the free tier one active. Point the elasic IP at the new machine for the duration of heavy load, then point it back at the free machine and deprovision the paid one.

Comment: What is the instance TYPE you are running, as described in this URL ?  https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-Day

1. Stop EC2 Instance
2. Re-size EC2 Instance to something bigger
3. Start EC2 Instance

Post-Day

1. Stop EC2 Instance
2. Re-size EC2 Instance to something smaller
3. Start EC2 Instance

To be fair, if you're on the free instance, whatever you're running on there I can pretty much guarantee that whatever huge spike in traffic you think you're going to get, you probably won't so you're probably worrying about something that is never going to happen.

But that's how you to it above. See here for the info on the different instances and performance capabilities, https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: Lol, that's exactly what my co-founder said to me about being so optimistic! But thank you for taking the time to answer my (most probably delusional) question. Really appreciate it. Have a great day!